# How to use intergrated graphics instead of dedicated

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics

I have a recent asus motherboard with an i7 processor and i've got a nvidia 670gtx connected to it.

For various reasons/experimentation purposes i'd like to connect my monitor to the intergrated graphics adapter rather than my gtx 670 card.

If i connect it to the motherboard's DVI connector the screen does not display any image on POST, nor when i'm actually in my OS, if i move the connector to the GTX card i get an image however.

Why is this happening? how can i use the intergrated graphics port to connect my monitor? (it must not involve disconnecting the GTX card)

Comment: Try disconnecting the gtx 670, then plugging into the onboard adapter, if there is still no change, update the post.

Answer (score 2):

There is likely an option in the BIOS that you can adjust to force the integrated GPU to be used by default.

I selected a board at random on ASUS's website (the new Z87-DELUXE) and looked through the manual. The setting you need to adjust appears to be `Primary Display` which is located in `Advanced` > `System Agent Configuration` > `Graphics Configuration` on this new board. By default, `Primary Display` is set to `Auto`; to force the integrated GPU to be used as the primary display output, select `iGPU` instead.

If you cannot locate this setting in your board's BIOS take a look through the BIOS section of the manual; it can easily be found on Asus's website if you do not have the booklet anymore.